# jQuery and AJAX - inserting values into POST parametres

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know I may seem as a most noobie question. I need to somehow insert this var into this parameter for POST request, not just writing the number in:

```
var x = 3;
id=(the var x needs to be here)&appid=440&name=hat&total=3&quantity=1
```

How should I do it? Like this?

```
id=+x+&appid=440&name=hat&total=3&quantity=1
```

Or how?
Thanks.

Comment: id = "x=" + x + "&appid=440&name=hat&total=3&quantity=1" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are simply trying to construct a url parameter string... if that's the case, just do a string concat like so and tack it onto the end of your url.

`var x = 3;
'www.myurl.com?id=' + x + '&appid=440&name=hat&total=3&quantity=1'`

or
`var data='id=' + x + '&appid=440&name=hat&total=3&quantity=1';`

For simple questions on syntax, open the dev panel ( F12 ) and go to the console tab.  Here you can type your statements and see immediately how they are evaluated.

[image]

Comment: But adding those + will make space next to the x, right? Or not?

Comment: No.  If you added a space in the string portion  (  var data = 'id= ' + x ) ... this would give you a space after id.
FYI - If you are using something like Chrome or Firefox, simply click F12 to open the dev panel.  Open the Console tab and type in your javascript.  This way you can see how your browser will interpret your statements immediately.   It will answer a lot of your questions.

Comment: @Messon , if this worked for you please check it as an answer so it will stay open ( feel free to accept ZedXter's as well as its literally the same advice ) Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, forgot. Thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well if id is a string, you have to do it this way:

```
var x = 3;
var data = 'id=' + x + '&appid=440&name=hat&total=3&quantity=1';
```

And then use `data` variable whenever you need it.